# Get gcc version and store it in a variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, gcc

I have my gcc compiler inside *'D:/Cygwin/bin'* . 
I created a batch file for deriving the version number of the gcc.

```
set gccPath=D:/Cygwin/bin 
for /f %%i in ('%gccPath%/gcc.exe -v') do @set versionInfo=%%i 
if defined versionInfo (echo found) else ^
echo not found
```

Here i am trying to store the output of the statement `gcc -v` to the variable `versionInfo`. But when i run this batch file, the output of the command is not stored in the variable. How can i store the information to the variable `versionInfo`?.

Answer (score 1):

```
set "gccPath=D:\Cygwin\bin"
set "versioninfo="
for /f %%i in ('%gccPath%\gcc.exe -v') do if not defined versioninfo set versionInfo=%%i
if defined versionInfo (echo found) else (echo not found)
```

`\` is path-separator on windows; `/` is switch-indicator.

You appear to have a trailing space on the `set gccpath` line. This would be included in the value assigned. The format with quotes is designed to prevent this exact thing - trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned.

The `@` is not required in a `set` (or any other) statement. `@echo off` is the traditional start to a batch - it means "turn `echo` off and don't `echo` this statement".

Batchers rarely use the `^` terminal to continue lines. I'd advise against it.

The extra `if not defined` statement gating the `set`ting of the variable ensures that the variable is set but once and if there are no further lines (you haven't shown us a typical output from `gcc -v`) the `set` is ignored, otherwise it would be overwritten by whatever is on the next line

Comment: Still it is coming as not found.

Comment: Also i tried with another example, when i use 'ver' command in command prompt, it gives the output 'Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]' . So in the above mentioned for loop, i gave 'ver' instead of that 'gcc command' , now the versionInfo has only Microsoft and not the complete info. How can we store the entire info?

Comment: `ver` is a standard batch command returning the version of the OS, and is not relevant to the current issue. As I said, `you haven't shown us a typical output from gcc -v` and without that data, we're reduced to a guessing game. Please post the complete output from executing the command `gcc -v` by editing it into your original post so that we can analyse the problem properly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The example in the prev comment is completely different. I posted it to show that even there (using 'ver' command) complete information is not stored in the variable. Only a part of it is stored. Now coming to the main problem(related to gcc), the output for gcc -v is given below.
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
....xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..............
localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC)